# Connecting oracle with ssl without oracle wallet

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, sqoop, sqoop2

Am trying in all the ways possible to make a ssl connection with Oracle server without using Oracle wallet.
All i found [this doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) to make ssl with wallet and could find no posts explains in step-by-step to achieve without wallet.

Please help me to make both server side and client side set up to make a ssl connection without wallet if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want to use Oracle Wallets, you can use JKS  Java KeyStore(JKS) instead.  Details for the same are provided in the white paper.  You need to pass the JKS file location and password as either connection properties or system properties.  JKS is used to connect to one of the cloud offerings from Oracle (EECS).  Check out the instructions (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc-eecloud-3089380.html) and follow the similar approach.

Comment: thank you, it helped me a lot :)